# Unit step function decomposition of piecewise constant function

Tags: functions

I need to express the following in term of the unit step function:

$ f(t) = \begin{cases} 0&  0\le t<3\\ -2&  3\le t<5\\ 2& 5\le t<7\\ 1& t\ge 7\end{cases} $

My solution:

$ f_1(t) = 0 $

$ f_2(t) = 0 - 2u_2(t) $

$f_3(t) = 0 - 2u_2(t) +4u_3(t) $

$f_4(t) = 0 - 2u_2(t) +4u_3(t) - 1u_4(t) $

$ f(t) = - 2u_2(t) +4u_3(t) - u_4(t) $

wondering if my working is correct

Comment: Why is the first jump at $2$? Why is the second jump at $3$? Why is the last jump at $4$? It seems to me that the jumps should be at $3$, $5$, and $7$.

Comment: why is that????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coefficients are correct but as stated by Ian in the comments, you are using the wrong Heaviside functions, you should be jumping at the intervals 3,5 and 7 because that is where your piecewise function changes value:

\begin{equation}
f(t)=-2u_3(t)+4u_5(t)-u_7(t)
\end{equation}

Check:

\begin{equation}
f(8)=-2+4-1=1 \\
f(6)=-2+4=2
\end{equation}

etc.

Comment: see [link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/StepFunctions.aspx) for the definition of the heaviside function

Answer (score 1):

If $u(t)$ is the unit step function, $f(t)$ can be written as

$$f(t)=-2u(t-3)+4u(t-5)-u(t-7)$$

Comment: any explanation for this ansswer?  thanks for your time

Comment: @javahelp: Well, $u(t-3)$ implements the  jump at $t=3$, $u(t-5)$ jumps at $t=5$, and $u(t-7)$ jumps at $t=7$. The factors take care of the height of the jump. First we go to $-2$ then up by $+4$ (resulting in $+2$), then again down by $1$, leaving us with a constant value of $1$ for $t>7$.